# Angular bevahior subject not updating property values when I click ' add task' button

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-directive, rxjs-observables

I have these components and I also am attaching code.

- A. ADD BUTTON
- B. ADD TASK
- C. HEADER
- D. LIST TASK.

AND A SERVICE MSGSERVICE THRU WHICH ADD BUTTON STREAM UPDATES AND ADD TASK SUBSCIBE TO THE UPDATES.

I want add task view to toggle when I click 'add task' button. It does not toggle back after the first display.

ADD BUTTON

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MsgService } from '../../services/msgservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addbutton',
  templateUrl: './addbutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addbutton.component.css'],
})
export class AddbuttonComponent {
  toggletask: boolean = false;
  togglebutton: boolean = false;
  constructor(private msg: MsgService) {}

  subcribe() {
    console.log('sending msg');
    this.msg.setMessage({
      toggleAddTask: !this.toggletask,
      toggleButton: !this.togglebutton,
    });
  }
}
```

html

```html
<div class="button"><button  (click)="subcribe()"> ADD TASK </button></div>
```

ADD TASK

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MsgService } from 'src/app/services/msgservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-addtask',
  template: `
    <form *ngIf="toggletask">
      <label for="taskdesc"> Task Name </label>
      <input type="text" id="taskdesc" /> <br />
      <label for="date"> Date: </label>
      <input type="text" id="date" /><br />
      <label for="complete"> Complete </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="complete" />
    </form>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class AddtaskComponent implements OnInit {
  toggletask: boolean = false;
  togglebutton: boolean = false;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private msg: MsgService) {
    this.subscription = this.msg.getMessage().subscribe((val) => {
      this.toggletask = val.toggleAddTask;
      console.log('toggle task val  ', val.toggleAddTask);
      this.togglebutton = val.toggleButton;
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    //throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    console.log('add task loaded inonint');
  }

  toggle(): void {
    this.msg.getMessage().subscribe((val) => {
      this.toggletask = val.toggleAddTask;
      console.log('toggle task val  ', val.toggleAddTask);
      this.togglebutton = val.toggleButton;
    });
  }
}
```

HEADER

```html
<p>header works!</p>
<app-addbutton />
```

MSGSERVICE

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MsgService {
  toggletask: boolean = false;
  togglebutton: boolean = false;

  msg: BehaviorSubject<{ toggleAddTask: boolean; toggleButton: boolean }> =
    new BehaviorSubject<{ toggleAddTask: boolean; toggleButton: boolean }>({
      toggleAddTask: false,
      toggleButton: false,
    });

  constructor() {}

  setMessage(message: { toggleAddTask: boolean; toggleButton: boolean }): void {
    let tgtask: boolean = this.toggletask;
    let tgbutton: boolean = this.togglebutton;

    this.msg.next({
      toggleAddTask: !tgtask,
      toggleButton: !tgbutton,
    });
    console.log('in setmsg', this.msg.value);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.msg));
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<{ toggleAddTask: boolean; toggleButton: boolean }> {
    console.log('in get', this.msg.value);

    return this.msg.asObservable();
  }
}
```

I have tried many different things but couldn't get it work and also had chat-gpt fully review code and Gentleman couldn't offer me a fix to this issue and suggested I check with forums. So please help if you can and this will be much appreciated.`

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in *setMessage* method of your **MsgService**. The following part of *setMessage* method:

```
let tgtask: boolean = this.toggletask;
let tgbutton: boolean = this.togglebutton;
```

should be updated to:

```
let tgtask: boolean = message.toggleAddTask;
let tgbutton: boolean = message.toggleButton;
```

Why? because when you use **this.toggletask**, it is taking variable local to your service which is always false and never changing. But setMessage is trying to set the value of behaviourSubject with the parameter value sent in the method itself. So your updated method will look like this:

```
setMessage(message: { toggleAddTask: boolean; toggleButton: boolean }): void {
    let tgtask: boolean = message.toggleAddTask;
    let tgbutton: boolean = message.toggleButton;

    this.msg.next({
      toggleAddTask: tgtask,
      toggleButton: tgbutton,
    });
    console.log('in setmsg', this.msg.value);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.msg));
  }
```

Comment: did what you suggested. Now nothing is happening.

Comment: Remove negation from values in **this.msg.next** as follows:

`this.msg.next({
      toggleAddTask: tgtask,
      toggleButton: tgbutton,
    });`

Also updating my answer

Comment: And btw, I don't understand why do you need **toggletask** and **togglebutton** local variables in MsgService. They're doing nothing in the service, you should remove them.

Comment: just to give you more context...I have tried all those combinations and few other things just to make it work but still no luck! I think issue is not the obvious one but how subject is used in the service.

Comment: One more thing i want to confirm from you is, are you subscribing before you're calling next or after you're calling next? 

For instance:

`mySubject.subscribe((val)=>{ console.log(val); }); 
  mySubject.next('Test');`

The above code will print Test on console. But if we change the chronology as follows:

`mySubject.next('Test');
  mySubject.subscribe((val)=>{ console.log(val); });`

It won't print anything, because you're subscibing after you've already published a value. So try to ensure that you're subscribing on getMessage method before calling setMessage method.

Comment: that is not correct. you set values before you subscribe and how you subscribe matters. thats probably what im doing wrong here.